# Derivation of the conditional variance of OLS

Tags: variance, least-squares

I was reading the notes by Matthew Blackwell from lecture 10 of his Quantitative Research Methodology [course](https://www.mattblackwell.org/files/teaching/gov2000/s10-multiple-regression.pdf) and ran into a couple moments that I do not understand:

**1. How does he go from line 2 to line 3 below?**

[image]

**2. How does he go from line 3 to line 4
below?**

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the first question, as you can find in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) for any constant (i.e. non-random) $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf {A}$ and constant $m\times 1$ vector $\mathbf {a}$, it holds that

$$\operatorname {var} (\mathbf {AX} +\mathbf {a} )=\mathbf {A} \,\operatorname {var} (\mathbf {X} )\,\mathbf {A} ^{\rm {T}}$$

And since you're conditioning on $X$, the matrix $X$ is a constant.

The second question is trivial linear algebra, you're multiplying one matrix $X'X$ with its inverse, which gives you the identity matrix: $AI=A$. Then since the assumption is that the error them is homoskedastic the variance of $u|X$ is $\sigma^2 I$, where each observation has the same variance $\sigma_u^2 = \sigma^2$.

Comment: With regards to the first question - got it, thank you. Do you happen to know if that variance property has a name? With regards to the second, I was asking what happens after X'X have given us the identity matrix. How do we go from sigma u to sigma and two sets of (X'X)^(-1) to only one of these.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.